# How to wordpress pagination url change

Tags: wordpress, pagination

How can I change wordpress pagination url?

For example:

```
websitenamee.com/cat/scottish-fold/page/2/
```

to:

```
websitenamee.com/cat/scottish-fold?page=2
```

I want do this for SEO purposes.

Can be the exact opposite. When the `/cat/scottish-fold?page=2` this link entered show this page `/cat/scottish-fold/page/2/` but url must be seen `/cat/scottish-fold/page/2/`.